# Docker Container is getting exited when launched through ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

Following is the roleA.yml

```
- name: Create container
  docker_container:
  name: my_container
  image: my_image:v0.2
  ports:
    - "0.0.0.0:8765:8765/tcp"
    - "0.0.0.0:80:80/tcp"
  state: started
  command: service apache2 restart
```

Below is the main.yml

```
- name: Launching container.
hosts: localhost
environment:
  PYTHONPATH: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
roles:
  - roleA
```

Following is the command i use to launch the container.

```
ansible-playbook main.yml
```

But whenever I execute this command, the container gets launched and within no seconds it gets exited. I even tried the different solutions suggested in [Fail to start container using docker_container module after docker for mac update](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/25291). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Please help. Thanks in advance.
Let me know if you need some more info.

Comment: What do you expect of `service apache2 restart` command? Not to exit?

Comment: Yes not to exit. I want to run few more commands by entering into the container once the container is up. But the container is going down immediately after executing that command

Comment: Of course, because the command you told Docker to run finishes; so the container exits too. Maybe it's time for you to have a first look how Docker works?

Comment: what i want to achieve is "docker run -it image_id bash" but through ansible. But I'm not finding the proper way in ansible document for this

Comment: Because your problem has nothing to do with Ansible. You seem to have no clue how Docker works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start apache service in foreground.

**[Run apache in the foreground](http://zroger.com/blog/apache-in-the-foreground/)**

```
$ apachectl -d . -f httpd.conf -e info -DFOREGROUND

-d . sets the ServerRoot to the current directory. All relative paths within the configuration file will resolve to this root.
-f httpd.conf sets the configuration file to use. Note that this is relative to the ServerRoot, not the current working directory. In this case, the ServerRoot is the current working directory, so httpd.conf needs to exist in the current working directory.
-e info sets the logging level for startup. This is different than the log level set in the configuration file.
-DFOREGROUND defines the special apache directive that will cause the parent process to run in the foreground and not detach from the shell.
```

Comment: The issue is not with apache. I'm fine to use any alternative commands too. But my container is going down immediately after executing whatever command i give. Is there any way to prevent it from going into stopped state?

Comment: try replacing your command with a newer command (service apache2 restart && tail -f /dev/null ) that will launch container and hence terminal will not get close automatically.

Comment: After trying the things you suggested, the container came up fine but the ports aren't seen as exposed.